# Query Result(NULL value/Datetime format)

Tags: sql, ssis

I have this query that I use for put all the rows in one column, is dynamic because I need to do this with at least 8 tables:

```
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(20) = 'Location'
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns, '') + '+[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],+'''''','''''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblName and TABLE_SCHEMA='LES'
select @columns

SET @sql = 'SELECT CONCAT(''''''''' + STUFF(@columns, 103,9, '') + '+'''''') FROM ' + @tblName
select @sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
R1: SELECT CONCAT(''''+[Location],+''','''+[Location Type],+''','''+[Region],+''','''+[World Region],+''','''+[Refresh Date]+''') FROM Location
```

If I execute the query (without the datetime column (Refresh Date) that contains NULL values) the result will be

```
'0020319389','CMF','AJ','AJ'
'0031209263','CMF','AJ','AJ'
'01BM','DCL','EU','EU'
'01CR','DCL','EU','EU'
```

My problem here is that when I execute the query with the `Refresh_date` column, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mixing old school concatenation, `+` with the 2012/2014 `CONCAT` function and data precedence rules are in effect.

This bit of code is using old school syntax

```
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns, '') + '+[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],+'''''','''''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblName and TABLE_SCHEMA='LES'
```

Instead, make it use a CONCAT, then your data type precedence will convert your date times to a string as well as handle NULLs.

Comment: Thanks billinkc this fixed a part of my problem, now the other problem is that for example I have NULL values in the Refresh_date column and I want to see NULL when I execute the query: SELECT CONCAT('''',[Location],''',''',[Location Type],''',''',[Region],''',''',[World Region],''',''',[Refresh Date],'''') FROM [LES].[Location] 

if I execute that query the result will be: 
'0020319389','CMF','AJ','AJ',''     ----If you see at the end of the result I have '' and here I want to see 'NULL' or the best for me is se NULL without ''